# Maven - use old jars from SVN

Tags: maven, jar

I am migrating J2ee project to Maven,
I was able to resolve 99% of its dependencies except 2 old jar files we wrote few years 
ago,

Is it possible to drop these jars somewhere (SVN repo?)

And tell the pom.xml to take the libraries from there?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myCompany </groupId>
    <artifactId>very old Jar</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <location>svn://archaic/jars/dont/move/this/jar1.jar</location>
</dependency>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep them in the project and add a system-scoped dependency, which [lets you specify a path to a local file as a dependency](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) using the "systemPath" element.

If you're switching to Maven, you might want to look at setting up your own repository manager both to handle this and to proxy outside repos for quicker access and convenient searching. [Nexus](http://nexus.sonatype.org/) is very popular and extremely [simple to set up](http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/install.html).

Comment: +1 for nexus, dump stuff in your personal nexus repository and decide on your own coordianates

Comment: Thanks you for your help.        
Will try it Monday morning.

Comment: Thank you! this helped, 
I Installed all of my old jars on apache archiva, Its working flawlessly!